# LINQ Expressions and this

Tags: c#, linq, reflection.emit

I want to use LINQ expressions to generate an instance method in a class using the Expression.CompileToMethod method. Not allowed to use reflection.emit for this bit of code and never used linq for anything besides LCG methods:( I need to access a field in the class. How do I access "this" using a LINQ expression?

Update : 
doesnt seem like it is supported. When I try to pass a methodbuilder into CompileToMethod that is not static then I get an argument exception. Can someone confirm that linq expressions can only be used to create static method?

```
AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("foo");
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                asmName,
                AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);


            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("foo");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
                "foo",
                TypeAttributes.Public,
                typeof(object));

            FieldInfo field = typeBuilder.DefineField("FooBar", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Private);
            ConstructorBuilder constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new[] { typeof(string) });

            // want to use linq expressions for constructor too.
            ILGenerator generator = constructor.GetILGenerator();
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field); 
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Bar", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

            Expression writeLine = Expression.Call(
                null,
                typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) }, null),
                Expression.Constant("The value is {0}"),
                Expression.Constant("no this")); //Expression.MakeMemberAccess("this", field)); // need to access this.

            Expression.Lambda<Action>(
                writeLine).CompileToMethod(method);


            Type myType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, "FooBar");
            MethodInfo barMethod = myType.GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            barMethod.Invoke(instance, null);
```

Update 2:
Looks like not supported

```
private void CompileToMethodInternal(MethodBuilder method, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
{
  ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull(method, "method");
  **ContractUtils.Requires(method.IsStatic, "method");**
```

Comment: Please post the code so that we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to use linq to compile some code that has access to "this" pretty straight forward. I will write a quick example though.

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `Expression.Constant`:

```
var thisExpr = Expression.Constant(this);
var fieldExpr = Expression.Field(thisExpr, "fieldName");
```

e.g.

```
public class ExprTest
{
    private readonly int value;
    public ExprTest(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Func<int> GetValueExpr()
    {
        var fieldExpr = Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(this), "value");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(fieldExpr);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}

var e = new ExprTest(5);
int i = e.GetValueExpr()();    //i == 5
```

Comment: Thank you but not really what i was looking for.  Looks like generating instance methods is not supported with LINQ expressions.

Comment: `Expression.Constant(this)` refers to the object creating the expression tree.  The OP wanted a `this` which refers to the object the expression tree is compiled to.